# Powershell run as User

Tags: powershell, command-line

How can I run a certain line in a powershell script as a different user.

For example I have this line

```
$server = $args[0];
Add-PSSnapin -Name McliPSSnapIn
Mcli-Run SetupConnection -p server=$server
```

and I want to encapsulate the last two lines to run as a different user, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a round about way of doing it, but:

```
$cred = Get-Credentials
$server = $args[0]
Start-Job -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Add-PSSnapin -Name McliPSSnapIn
    Mcli-Run SetupConnection -p server=$server
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

I don't think this will exactly give the results you're hoping to achieve. What are you trying to do?